# Is it possible to use ShareActionProvider and Share App Extension with Ionic2?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2

I'm looking at different options to start my new `iOS/Android` project. Since there is a touch of social, one of my requirement is to allow the user to share very easily stuff using quick share integration. I would like to know if there are any limitations using `ActionProvider` and `App Extension` using `Ionic2`?

Any additional documentation will help me making a decision.